Nuxt Dynamic Route Issue: ID Switching to 'preload.js.map' Unexpectedly
I have a very simple dynamic route. The page is in the following directory: ~/pages/explore/initiative/[id].vue
When I navigate to that page via NuxtLink, it seems to be making the request several times.
I added the following code to [id].vue to verify if this is the case
const route = useRoute()
const initiativeId = route.params.id;
console.log("Route Params: ", route.params.id);

Here's an example of the output
Route Params:  18

 WARN  [@vue/server-renderer] Skipped rendering unsafe attribute name: "

Route Params:  preload.js.map

So it seems that the ID is being switched to preload.js.map. I didn't write any code to that switch, so it seems to be the framework making the request or some other package included within.
Not sure if this is relevant, but there's also an index.vue page in ~/pages/explore/initiative/index.vue

I'm curious to see what else is going on on the page. In any case, just for fun, when troubleshooting, try making the initiativeId a computed: const initiativeId = computed(() =>route.params.id), and then console.log: console.log("Route Params: ", initiativeId.value). Moreover, move the console.log to onMounted and see what happens. Just giving you things to try.
